# How to setup wordpress multi site on nitrous.io

Tags: wordpress, nitrousio

I am using nitrous.io and have attempted to setup wordpress multi-site using the instructions here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

It breaks after step 4 when I attempt to login after changing the wp-config.php and .htaccess file.

I am choosing the sub directory option.

I get stuck in an endless redirect loop.

I have attempted taking out the port number 80 which wordpress put in the following line.

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'publicurlhere.com')
```

Still no luck.

I believe this has something to do with it being hosted on port 3000 and a problem with proxy settings from nitrous.io that wordpress can't handle.

EDIT

I changed the port to 3000

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'publicurlhere.com:3000')
```

And now I get the message:

```
    Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the wordpress docs it looks like this is a limitation of wordpress and will not work on a different port.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network

```
You cannot create a network in the following cases:

     "WordPress address (URL)" uses a port number other than ':80', ':443'.
```